# Exponential Circuit

Tags: voltage-divider, logic-gates

I want to amplify a voltage by x to the power of x/4. So, basically, if I have 9 milivolts, I want it to amplify to 9<sup>2.25</sup> milivolts.

Simple enough in theory, but I've so far found no actual way to do this in an analog way, and I don't want to include a microcontroller into this otherwise simple project. This only goes up to 10 volts, so I thought about simply using multiple transistors that multiply with a different value, but since this is signal processing, I can't get around the comma, unfortunately.

Is there any type of logic that could rectify that problem, or do I have to turn to MPUs?

Comment: A voltage divider is easy. Follow this with a voltage to current converter that works exponentially (BJT or diode), then convert that current to a voltage (resistor.) Most people call this *distortion* and try to get rid of it.

Comment: That's an unusual requirement. Can the signal processing algorithm be reorganized so that this function is not required? It will be very difficult to accurately create this function because of the dynamic range it would require. What is the signal processing you're doing?

Comment: X/4 is not  the same as 2.25 but this is possible with log or anti-log gain circuits respectively

Comment: Your question is incomplete , please answer in question... if with wanted \$9mV^{2.25}= 140.296 mV\$ what about 10mV ? 0mV? -9mV?

Comment: BTW \$X * X^{0.25}=X^{1.25}\$ Is that what you meant for X>0?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 the question is badly worded - should be 'raise a voltage, x, to the power x/4'

Comment: TY @Chu , not only that but polarity,  BW and range is clouded in mystery

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic structure:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flbX7K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The basic principle is to exploit the exponential nature of the diode response.

Comment: Does inverting work for the Op?

Comment: Does it scale properly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the exact implementation as a circuit but it may be helpful to write your function this way:

$$
\begin{align}
A(v) &= v^{v/a} \\
\ln A(v) &= \frac{v}{a}\ln v \\
   A(v) &= \exp \left( \frac{v}{a} \ln v \right)
\end{align}
$$
Here \$a\$ is a constant, like 4 mV in your example.

This last formula can be computed using analog logarithm, exponentiation and multiplier modules.